# Set property of IBOutlet

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I created an outlet by draggin & dropping an `UIImageView` into the `ViewController.swift` file

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

I want to set the property of `imageView` to

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Doing this

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView! {
    self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

XCode complains that

> @IBOutlet attribute requires property to be mutable

How do I go on about this?

Comment: Why not set those properties in the storyboard?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're trying to do is a perfectly acceptable way to set up an `@IBOutlet`'s properties… just don't reference other `@IBOutlet`s, or the main view, etc, as this may force the main view to load earlier than expected.

You just need to wrap your code inside a `didSet` block…

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView! {    
    didSet {
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An outlet is basically just a link to that UI element in the storyboard.

So you link your `UIImageView` in the storyboard to an element in your UIViewController code and then you can access and change properties of that element once it is loaded.

**The Problem**

This is the wrong syntax for doing this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView! {
    self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

The reason for the following error

> @IBOutlet attribute requires property to be mutable

is.. having a closure after a property declaration acts as a getter. As an example I can do this

```
let two = 2
let three = 3

var five: Int {
   return two + three
}
```

I cannot set any of the above values. two and three are let only (read only constants) and five is a computed property, so I can also only read that. I wont complicate the matter further but I would highly recommend giving this part of the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) a read when you can.

**Solution**

You should have an outlet only:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

and then somewhere else in the code you can do things with it.

I think in your case it would be best on viewDidLoad. ViewDidLoad is called after the view and all of its outlets and properties have been set. So this is a safe place to start to use your outlets to further configure your view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's **not** good approach to override outlet's getter.
Secondly, technically you can override getter and setter of outlet.

In your case you defined getter, and forgot about setter. So you got `get only` variable.

```
    private var _someView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var someView: UIImageView! {
    get {
        self.someView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        self.someView.clipsToBounds = true
        return _someView
    }
    set {
        _someView = newValue
    }
}
```

You should use private variable to avoid recursion in getter.

Answer (score 0):

Just try in this way and invoke this method inside viewDidLod()

```
func createRoundGreenImage(imageView : UIImageView, with image : 
String) {
self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```